# Delphi 2007 Import a Type Library

Tags: delphi, dllimport, pkcs#11

In Delphi 2007 i'm trying to Import a type library and i get an error message:

> error occured during loading library type/DLL.

I want to import libraries: pkcs11.dll, libp11.dll
The libraries have been prepared in VisualStudio 2017.

I tried to use command-line tool tlibimp, but without effects.

> ```
> c:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\Projects\TEST>tlibimp -p pkcs11.dll
> Borland TLIBIMP Version 11.0
> Copyright (c) 1997-2005 Borland Software Corporation
> Error loading type library pkcs11.dll.
> ```

Maybe someone knows how to solve this problem?

I tried to do regsvr32 pkcs11.dll but i get the message: DllRegisterServer entry point was not found.

I also tried to find pkcs11.tlb in VS project but it does not exist.

I installed the Dependency Walker "depends.exe" and saw that some libraries are missing:

> ```
> API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL
> API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
> API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL
> API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
> DCOMP.DLL
> IESHIMS.DLL
> ```

I have installed Visual Studio 2017 and why are not there ? Where to get them ?

---

As Eugene explained, PKCS#11 API doesn't export any type libraries and i need to import function. I found 2 tools:

> ```
> 1. 23991_c_to_pascal_converter_1.0 from Embarcadero
> 2. GUIHeadConv from Dr. Bob
> ```

Comment: That message can come up if there is no Type Library resource in the DLL or EXE at all or if the type library had not been registered first.   Maybe try "regsvr32 pkcs11.dll" and then try the import again.  Alternatively, if there is a "pkcs11.tlb" from the VS project  you might try the import using that instead of the dll.

Comment: @DaveOlson, Can you expand that into an answer?

Comment: @Johan, I felt that my suggestions were closer to some guesses rather than a definitive answer.  I was going to compose an answer after Leko tried one or more my suggestions and have some more data to work with.

Comment: @leko, the "DllRegisterServer" message you received from "regsvr32" explains the "Error loading type library" message you're getting from the "tlibimp" import:  There doesn't appear to be a Type Library resource, ActiveX control or COM server in "pkcs11.dll".  Delphi is not the problem here.  It all has to do with the VS2017 project and the building of it.

Comment: You may want to add VS2017 to the tags of your question and you might want to remove the Delphi tag as I'm confident "tlibimp" will work just fine once you sort the VS issues out.  I am not familiar enough with VS or the building of ActiveX/Com Servers using VS to be of much help here.  Sorry.

Comment: One last thought:  Those missing DLLs would prevent "pkcs11.dll" from being loaded properly by "regsvr32" an thus "DllRegisterServer" entry point would *appear* to be missing.  Once you locate those missing DLLs, try the regsvr32 again.  Once that is successful the "tlibimp" may very well work.

Comment: PKCS#11 API doesn't export any type libraries. If you plan to use PKCS#11 API, you need to import functions rather than expect a type library in your DLLs.